# How to check if site is created by wordpress?

Tags: customization

Can anybody tell me that how to check if someone created his site using wordpress?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question. Clearly the OP of this question asked  on `How to check if a website is using WordPress`, not trying to be shy of the fact the website is created in WordPress.

Comment: Yeah @DenIsahac Is absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Probably.
Just Type `wp-admin` at the end of your domain like following:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin
```

Comment: Also Check: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/site-built-in-wordpress/

Comment: ps: I usually put the WordPress core into it's own subdirectory for easier maintainance, so this might not work for all installs of WordPress

Comment: @birbire thanks for our comment.I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to check it :

- As @nman said, you can try to type `/wp-admin`
- You can open source code and search for `/wp-content/themes/theme_name`

Answer (score 0):

## [`Wappalyzer`](https://wappalyzer.com/)

> Wappalyzer is a cross-platform utility that uncovers the technologies used on websites. It detects content management systems, ecommerce platforms, web frameworks, server software, analytics tools and many more.

The tool is available as a browser extension.

Though the results aren't always accurate, and since **WordPress** can be easily identified by scanning the *HTML* contents then **99%** of a time it gets **WordPress** easily.